# Why all atoms in an element $\rm Pt$ have different shapes and size?

Tags: atomic-physics, orbitals

When we imagine about an atom, the very first image comes in our mind is a sphere. But after watching the video below, that seems not true.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqLlgIaz1L0

So my question is, why all atoms in an element (such as platinum) have different shapes and size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get this idea? I watched the video and nothing like that was even mentioned. All platinum atoms are about the same size and shape unless an atom is excited. So there is no answer to  your question since the atoms do not all have different shapes and sizes.

Comment: Watch between 01:09 to 01:25. Are not they individual atoms at different angles?

Comment: @user248881 The views you reference between 1:09 to 1:25 are from the Pt video are of single NANOPARTICLE at different angles. The 27,000 (or so) atoms inside the nanoparticle are the same size and shape.

Comment: @Jeffrey J Weimer Yes you are right! I am so sorry. It was my misunderstanding.